# Twitter login integration?

Tags: android, authentication, twitter-login

I am integrating twitter login in my app. I am able to get session and access token successfully.Its also giving me email, user name. But I need user first name ,last name and user image.How can I get user profile details.I have written following code:

```
ivTwitterLogin.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                mTwitterAuthClient.authorize(getActivity(), new com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback<TwitterSession>() {

                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
                        TwitterSession session =twitterSessionResult.data;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                        ToastUtils.showToastShort(context, "Login failed");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the profile image from AccountService#verifyCredentials which returns a User object.

```
      Call<User> call = Twitter.getApiClient(session)
        .getAccountService()
        .verifyCredentials(true, false);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<User> result) {
        // Do something with user object
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @user23878962 ,
Will you please provide me complete request params and end point.

Comment: Are you wanting to get the profile image of the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read twitter documentation. Do they allow you to access profile pic? Also sometimes user may have not allowed in his/her settings to share details with anyone.